# In WebStorm, Unresolved variable xxx when Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I found that when using Angular in WebStorm, if you give the async pipe a value that is set to an empty array by default, it is marked as Unresolved variable `visitName`.

**WebStorm:**

[image]

**VSCode:**

[image]

It is correct when async is not used:

[image]

That solves the problem, but it doesn't feel good。

```
/**html**/
[nzData]="(reverseRecordsCurAppoint$ | async)?.list || reverseRecordsCurAppointDef"

/**ts**/
reverseRecordsCurAppointDef: Array<GetIpVisitTransPageListResp> = [];
```